# How can I use tag in locale file in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I'm using `<a href>` in locale file, I have to add `.html_safe` to somewhere in the bottom.

How can I fix it?

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= content_tag :div, msg.html_safe, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
```